# Javascript form - different email based on choice

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

I am using a javascript form with a server-side processor and I want to be able to have the form go to different emails based on the dropdown. I've gotten as far as I could based on other forms but I can't seem to get the emails to go through.   I have added under the option tag on the email addresses for the choices and changed the value from an overall form email to "mailTo" () I am pretty sure this is where the issue is but I don't know how to fix it.

```html
<form action="http://www.testsite.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" method="post" name="hgmailer">
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="mailTo">
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Website Consult Request">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="10px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Nearest Location*</td>
      <td><select id="mailTo" name"mailTo">
       <option value="option1@testsite.com">Option1</option>
       <option value="option2@testsite.com">Option2</option>
       <option value="option3@testsite.com">Option3</option>
       <option value="option4@testsite.com">Option 4</option>

       </select></td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table><p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="button" value="Schedule a Consultation" onclick="hgsubmit();" class="button">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thankyou.html">
</form>
```

Comment: So, you set the value of the selected option into the hidden field called `recipient`? and that's not working?

Comment: When you submit the form, if you for example selected the first option, the http POST request will have a parameter called `mailTo=option1@testsite.com`. It will also have another parameter called `recipient=mailTo`. In the server side, if you are trying to extract the email address from the `recipient` parameter it won't be there, try extracting it from the `mailTo` parameter instead.

Comment: You __need__ to validate this server-side, otherwise you are just creating a spam system that will allow sending emails to _every_ possible recipient. Best practice is something like having an array with the possible recipient addresses on the server side, and to use the array index as option values only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - My final code did not save previously

What you can do is add a javascript function to change the value of "recipient" to the selected email like...

```js
function changeVal() {
var selectedVal = document.getElementById("mailTo").value;
document.getElementById("recipient").value = selectedVal;

var test = document.getElementById("recipient").value;
//alert(test);
  
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.testsite.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" method="post" name="hgmailer">
    <input type="hidden" name="recipient" id="recipient" value="mailTo">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Website Consult Request">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="10px">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Nearest Location*</td>
          <td><select id="mailTo" name"mailTo" onchange="changeVal()">
           <option value="option1@testsite.com">Option1</option>
           <option value="option2@testsite.com">Option2</option>
           <option value="option3@testsite.com">Option3</option>
           <option value="option4@testsite.com">Option 4</option>
    
           </select></td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table><p>&nbsp;</p>
    <input type="button" value="Schedule a Consultation" onclick="hgsubmit();" class="button">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thankyou.html">
    </form>
```

...I added an alert that you can comment out if you would like to test. Also I did this in javascript and not Jquery as you only asked for that.